# Call again scrapy with new URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

This is my spider and it is working but, how could I send another spider on new found URL. Now, I´m storing all links whose begin with `HTTP`, `HTTPS` or if it is `/` I add the base URL.

Then I will iterate that array and call a new spider on the new URL (It is on the end of the code)

I can´t scrape on the new URL (I know because `print()` is not showing on the console)

```
import scrapy
import re

class GeneralSpider( scrapy.Spider ):
    name = "project"
    start_urls = ['https://www.url1.com/',
                'http://url2.com']

    def parse( self, response ):
        lead = {}
        lead['url'] = response.request.url
        lead['data'] = {}
        lead['data']['mail'] = []
        lead['data']['number'] = []

        selectors = ['//a','//p','//label','//span','//i','//b','//div'
                    '//h1','//h1','//h3','//h4','//h5','//h6','//tbody/tr/td']
        atags = []

        for selector in selectors:
            for item in response.xpath( selector ):
                name = item.xpath( 'text()' ).extract_first()
                href = item.xpath( '@href' ).extract_first()

                if selector == '//a' and href is not None and href !='' and href !='#':
                    if href.startswith("http") or href.startswith("https"):
                        atags.append( href )

                    elif href.startswith("/"):
                        atags.append( response.request.url + href )

                if href is not None and href !='' and href !='#':
                    splitted = href.split(':')

                    if splitted[0] not in lead['data']['mail'] and splitted[0] == 'mailto':
                        lead['data']['mail'].append(splitted[1])

                    elif splitted[0] not in lead['data']['number'] and splitted[0] == 'tel':
                        lead['data']['number'].append(splitted[1])

                else:
                    if name is not None and name != '':
                        mail_regex = re.compile( r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$' )
                        number_regex = re.compile( r'^(?:\(\+?\d{2,3}\)|\+?\d{2,3})\s?(?:\d{4}[\s*.-]?\d{4}|\d{3}[\s*.-]?\d{3}|\d{2}([\s*.-]?)\d{2}\1?\d{2}(?:\1?\d{2})?)(?:\1?\d{2})?$' )

                        if name not in lead['data']['mail'] and re.match( mail_regex, name ):
                            lead['data']['mail'].append(name)

                        elif name not in lead['data']['number'] and re.match( number_regex, name ):
                            lead['data']['number'].append(name)

        print( lead )
        #I want here call parse method again but with new url
        for tag in atags:
            scrapy.Request( tag, callback=self.parse )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the Request object in your function.
Since you are generating multiple ones, you can use `yield`, like this:

`yield scrapy.Request(tag, callback=self.parse)`

"In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return either dicts with extracted data, Item objects, **Request objects**, or an **iterable of these objects**." [See scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spiders)